# Add page numbers to PDF bookmarks

Tags: page-numbering, bookmarks

Is there a way to add page numbers to the PDF bookmarks?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\section{Section the First}
This is page 1.
\newpage
This is page 2.
\newpage
\section{Section the Second}
This is page 3.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin Scharrer's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417706/16967) is a good starting point. However, the asynchronous output routine makes `\thepage` unreliable and requires the use of page labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{refcount}

% Section numbers in bookmarks (more important than page numbers)
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\makeatletter

% Unique names for internal labels
\newcount\APTB@Count
\APTB@Count=\z@
\newcommand*{\APTB@LabelName}{APTB\the\APTB@Count}

% \label is a no-op inside the hook
\AtBeginDocument{\let\APTB@Label\label}

% The hook implementation for adding page numbers to bookmarks
\newcommand*{\APTB@AddPageToBookmark}{%
  % Set label and retrieve page number.
  \begingroup
    \global\advance\APTB@Count\@ne
    \APTB@Label{\APTB@LabelName}%
    \refused{\APTB@LabelName}%
    \protected@xdef\APTB@ThePage{%
      % \thepage is used as default, then the page number is at
      % least close.
      \getrefbykeydefault{\APTB@LabelName}{page}{\thepage}%
    }%
  \endgroup
  % Add page number to bookmark
  \edef\bookmark@text{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\bookmark@text}%
    \space(\unexpanded\expandafter{\APTB@ThePage})%
  }%
}

% Activate bookmark hook
\bookmarksetup{addtohook={\APTB@AddPageToBookmark}}

\makeatother

% Test
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

There are already some PDF viewers that automatically show the page numbers in bookmarks. And the page numbers can easily be compared:

- [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince):

  > [image: Screenshot of Evince's bookmarks]
- [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/):

  > [image: Screenshot of Okular's bookmarks]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `addtohook` option of `bookmark` to change the bookmark text stored in `\bookmark@text` to add the page number (`\thepage`).

Note that I'm nut 100% sure if the page numbers are always correct as `\thepage` might be off if TeX needs to process a lot of text before it decides where to break the page. In this case an internal reference would be needed to get a correct page number on the second TeX run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\bookmarksetup{addtohook={\edef\bookmark@text{\bookmark@text\space (\thepage)}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section the First}
This is page 1.
\newpage
This is page 2.
\newpage
\section{Section the Second}
This is page 3.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good starting point. I have extended it by using page references to deal with the asynchronous output routine.